# What's the best way to shore up a ceiling register that is loose?

Tags: vent, ceiling

I have a few ceiling registers which are not flush with the ceiling since the duct has loosened over time.  What's the best way to get them flush with the ceiling?  I thought about driving several sheet metal screws into them but they would go into drywall which has only so much holding strength. Is there a better method?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drill a hole on either side of the register.  Mark the holes on the ceiling with a pencil, drill and install a drywall anchor in each location.  Secure the register with screws into the anchor.

Some people paint the ceiling and the register so it blends in better (and covers the screw heads).

Comment: I didn't have much luck.  The metal tab of the vent doesn't overlap the drywall by enough to hold a drywall screw.  
What I need is a clip of sorts that would push the vent up from the drywall.

Comment: You could always glue it.

Comment: A contractor I had doing some other work simply put a 2x2 strip on top of the drywall and screwed into that. But it was only possible since we already had a hole in ceiling for a dryer vent.

Answer (score 1):

I cut thin strips of cardboard (small enough to fit in screw hole) and poked them in the holes.  Screws tightened nicely.  All you are trying to do is give the screw something to hold to.  Don't overfill or pack the hole.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 0):

I found some more registers that the previous homeowner completed stripped the screws on. I put a glob of JB weld on the problematic hole, completely covering it. Came back the next day and drilled a small hole through it and carefully screwed in the register. I was skeptical but it held very well and tight! On another register I drilled another hole into the sheet metal to solve the same problem. BTW, I highly recommend a socket and not screwdriver for removing/tightning.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, I installed a couple of 'leaf springs' on a plastic register and it stays in place very well.  Here's a link to a video I made for it.

https://youtu.be/bHWa9MCxrDQ

The Wright Handyman

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.] And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.